# Any good Java HTML parsers?

Tags: java, html, xpath

I was using Cobra until now because of how easy it was but unfortunately it had some problem with a few test cases. Does anyone suggest a tried-and-tested library?

I've tried Cobra's built in one and HTMLCleaner without any luck.

Comment: Judging by your last question, the problem isn't with "XPath evaluator". You were using `XPathFactory.newInstance()`, which creates the stock Java evaluator that works on any XML document loaded in a DOM model (as instance of `Document`). CORBA itself isn't an XPath evaluator - it's an HTML parser which produces `Document`, and it did that wrong in your case. So what you actually want is a "good Java HTML parser", not "good Java XPath evaluator".

Comment: Oops... sorry. I've revised my question... I'm just going nuts with all the HTML in front of my eyes...

Comment: I'm sure this same question was on SO earlier this week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mozilla HTML Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozillaparser/files/) looks rather interesting. By definition, it's supposed to be as good as Gecko engine itself, which is likely to cover your needs.

Answer (score 4):

[TagSoup](http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is really great when dealing with crappy HTML/XHTML.

[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) (and [NekoHTML](http://www.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/html/)) are good too to parse non valid HTML.

TagSoup and Jericho: tried-and-tested. NekoHTML: feedback from trustable source.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com) (no, I'm not involved in any way with the product, just a satisfied user).

Comment: Saxon is an awesome XSLT 2.0 & XQuery implementation, but it doesn't parse HTML.

Comment: @Pavel - The original question didn't mention HTML

Answer (score 1):

[Answering the title - the overall question and comments are not consistsent]

JTidy (http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) is a port of Dave Raggett's HTMLTidy. It's very useful though I think development may have slowed/ceased.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Validator.nu's parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/), based on the HTML5 parsing algorithm. (Mozilla is currently in the process of replacing its own HTML parser with this one.)